# Plot Aggregation in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

[image]

I am trying to set up a chart like in the image on this question. How do I plot this aggregation (I believe it's an aggregation. Please correct me if I am wrong) in PowerBI. The data is coming from SQL Server.

I tried to plot each section but it didn't make sense because the chart I am trying to plot looked like multiple groups